# Textarea problem

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to expand the textarea but fail somehow. It gets larger than the content. Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6S77z/1/). Why does it fail?

EDIT: Seems my question is not clear enough so let me put some clearness on it. What I want is to turn any textarea (that may have scrollbars because its content overflows) into the textarea that has such dimensions that the scrollbars disappear because the content does not overflow anymore.

**Why does my solution not work?** That's what I am wondering. **If I remove that "thisissomeverylongwordintheworld", it does work as intended.**

EDIT 2: I just tested the jsfiddle in Chrome and the textarea has a scrollbar... so I guess there is some problem with *scrollWidth* and *scrollHeight*... or I don't understand them right? :)

Comment: What dimensions are you trying to give it?

Comment: You are trying to expand the textarea? From my point of view it seems, that it is expanding it perfectly. What are you trying to do? For the record, in this case the content is the text.. and it is not larger then the content, or did you mean the window-viewpoint?

Comment: Peter Olson, you'll see it in the jsfiddle I posted. Kalle H. Väravas, the textarea gets far higher than it should be according to the text.

Comment: This question is very vague. Are you trying to make the textarea autogrow? Are you trying to make it simply scrollable? Are you trying to set the height of the textarea to the viewpoints (the window you are looking in) dimension?

Comment: Kalle H. Väravas, I am trying to make it so that there is no need for scrollbars but also I don't want any extra space. My problem is that I get that extra space (height) as you can see in the jsfiddle. Let me know if that is not clear yet.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/6S77z/7/ This is what I get out from your question. No css, no JS in fact.. Expands from the default size, but not too much. This fits your questions specifications (read: it doesn't specify anything)

Comment: In your jsfiddle there is a scrollbar, so that is not what I need.

Comment: @Flow: It was a joke, regarding on how little details you provided :) I hope you get the point however, because more detailed question will only get you more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a DIV with [**contenteditable=true**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/content_editable):

http://jsfiddle.net/6S77z/6/

Comment: That increases the width. The width must the same, only the height should change because the height is scrollable as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/6S77z/3/

Comment: Sorry that is not what I meant by "no css". I wrote about the problem above though.

Comment: @Flow: You didn't mention "no css" anywhere!

Comment: I edited my question. Hope it makes more sense now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still not clear. But probably you (if not now, then you will after you get the idea) want the autogrow textarea plugin. This is a script, that is running on my website, the original author is unknown. But it works..

**Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/6S77z/9/**
*(Try to delete your text, it will adopt to your actions [adding or removing text])*

Point is, that when the document (your website) is loaded, it will calculate the text amount inside the textarea. Then it will autogrow the textarea fitting the text amount/length. It doesn't produce a scrollbar (meats your requirement), doest use css (your requirement) and doesn't leave any extra space (well, one line.. at the bottom, that is necessary.)

I marked where the plugin starts and ends.. Also where is the trigger:

```
$('textarea').autogrow();
```

**PS:** You can set the width of the textarea with CSS or with [`cols=""`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_cols.asp).

**EDIT: Why doesn't your code work:**

What is not working? The code is meant to calculate the texts amount and adjust the textarea accordingly. That is what it does. There is no scrollbar on the textarea:

[image]

There is, however, a scrollbar on the window..as the textarea is very long.. Do you want no scrollbars on textarea, and also no scrollbars on the window?

**That is not possible!** I mean, your requirements are:

- No css
- No scrollbar on the textarea *critical*
- No scrollbar on the window *critical*
- Cant change the textareas width *critical*
- Cant delete any text *critical*

Those requirements mean, NOT POSSIBLE. You must give out on some *critical* requirement if you wish to continue.. But no scrollbars whatsoever, is not possible in any way.. its against physics.. **You cannot put a bigger box inside smaller box, without changing the boxes dimensions!**

Comment: That's great, but why my solution doesn't work? That's what I am wondering. If I remove that "thisissomeverylongwordintheworld", it does work as intended.

Comment: @Flow: Your code is not producing any scrollbars on the textarea. You are basically chasing your own tail here. You MUST HAVE some scrollbars somewhere, if there is too much content. Either on the textarea OR the window. Your script is working on the fact, that it doesn't produce any scrollbars. And let me point out that you are using css, in your jQuery.. but it is still css..

Comment: Also FYI, there are scrollbars in your demo when run in the latest Opera. No scrollbars in FF though.

Comment: Please forget about CSS. I wrote about CSS by mistake. As to my jsfiddle, you're right there are no scrollbars, but it is higher than needed. Can't you see that?

Comment: "but it is higher than needed." You haven't set any requirements or limits on "what it needs to be." Do you mean a textarea character limit? Do you mean a fixed height?